# Multiple Range Keys for DynamoDB table

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Is there anyway to support more than 2 keys in a DynamoDB table?
I have assessments that user fill and I need to index by user and assessment (several types of assessment each with different unique names). However, I also want to allow users to store different answers to each assessment (e.g. different dates or different contexts)
My data structure for assessment answers is:

- Sort key["S"]: IDUser (User ID from AWS Cognito that has answered)
- Range key["S"]: IDAssessment (unique assessment name)
- Answers["M"] in which the different answers to the assessment are stored
- Additional key ["S"]: to differentiate between assessments by name or date

My data structure for assessments schemas (that define a schema) is:

- Sort key["S"]: IDAssessment (unique assessment name)
- Range key["S"]: IDUser (User ID from AWS Cognito that owns the assessment)
- Additional key ["S"]: to classify the assessments by types and access them by type
- Name["S"] of the assessment
- Categories["M"] the map containing the assessment questions and levels

I think that requires at least three keys in Dynamo DB (user, assessment, answer-name) however it only allows me to create a sort and range key
Is there any way to do it? Am I missing something?
Thanks everyone

Comment: You can setup [Secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html), or you could create composite keys by combining attributes. Its really not clear what you are trying to achieve though. Why do you think you need 3 keys? Can you describe your data and schema in more detail?

Comment: Thanks Stu. Very useful. Have updated the structure on the question as requested. Thinking through the database structure I don't think I really need another key for the assessment answers as I can just store the data in different maps within the same item. For the Assessment Schema the secondary index is perfect to be able to select schemas by type

Comment: OK, and what queries do you want to be able to do? Also, Sort Key and Range Key are the same thing, I think you need to change Sort Key for Partition Key in your question.

Comment: I will read up on partition keys. Extremely helpful. I am new to NoSQL and it takes a different way of thinking compared to traditional relational databases

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by creating a Secondary index for each of your additional columns and making your column the index sort key.